# Finding matrix elements given a set of solutions for system of ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling to solve this problem, may be someone here can assist:

Given a function $f(\vec{x(t)},u(t))=\dot{\vec{x}}(t)-A\vec{x}-\vec{D}u(t)$,

where $x(t):R\to R^n$,

$u(t):R\to R$,

$D$ is a constant vector $(n\times 1)$, and $A$ is a constant matix $(n\times n)$.

By choosing pairs of $(\vec{x},u)$ that solves $f=0$ and assuming $u(t)$ is bounded (in $L^2$),  How can I find or estimate $A,D$?

the solution for $x$ is well known : $\vec{x}=\vec{x}_{0}e^{At}+e^{At}*\vec{D}u(t)$
,$x_{0}$ is the initial condition, but lets assume that $x_{0}=0$

I started by showing that the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ must be negative in order for the components of $x$ to be bounded as well. Secondly, by taking the fourier transform of $f=0$, I got $(i\omega I-A)\tilde{x}(\omega)=D\tilde{u}$

now by choosing $u(t)=\delta(t)$ we get:
$\sqrt{2\pi}\tilde{x}(\omega)=(i\omega I-A)^{-1}D$
But I don't know how to continue from here, I guess that another equ. is needed to solve the problem.
I also tried to think of the problem as a linear regression problem but i didn't get far with it.